# How to route port based o specific path in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, routes, portforwarding, nginx-ingress

I have two services and use port forward to forward them in different prots of local host. For example service1 can be visited via `localhost:port1`, service2 can be visited via `localhost:port2`.

At some point during the workflow in service1, in service1 UI, a new link like `"localhost:port1/_/path"` is generate. But it actually works in service2 for that link. I can visit then link by changing port1 to port2 but I can't visit with the generated link. I mean I can visit `"localhost:port2/_/path"` other than "`localhost:port1/_/path"` which is generated by service1 backend. I want to do a port routing if path`"_/path"` is present in service1. How can I do that? I read the ingress documentation and can't find port routing examaples.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to deploy nginx ingress controller and setup path based routing. follow the link for reference

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/ingress-path-matching.md

Comment: Thank you! I solved this problem by configuring istio-ingress gateway.